# Unpaired <form> tag

Tags: css, html, forms

I don't understand, why an unpaired <form> tag behaves like that. I have been expecting that CSS selector will be applied only on <form>. But it is applied on everything after the unpaired <form />. Can you explain that please? Thank you in advance :)

```
<style>
  form { font-size: 20px; color: red; }
</style>

<form id="a">
  <label>Styled label inside &lt;form&gt;</label>
</form>

<p>
  Unstyled text, outside &lt;form&gt;, inside &lt;p&gt;
</p>

<form id="search" action="search.php" method="post" />

<label>Label after unpaired &lt;form /&gt;</label>
<br />
<input form="search" type="text" />
<input form="search" type="submit" value="Search" />

<p>
  Text after unpaired &lt;form /&gt;, inside &lt;p&gt;. Why is it styled?
</p>
```

EDIT: I have edited the code; there was bad example before. Somewhere I saw example of using unpaired <form /> as an "sheet" for controls.

For example, you have two unpaired <form />:

```
<form id="order" action="order.php" method="post" />
<form id="search" action="search.php" method="get" />
```

First is for sending orders, second for searching. Some controls on page will use the "order" <form />, others the "search" <form />. They are connected with the right <form /> with form attribute.

Comment: So you're wondering why you get unexpected results with invalid HTML?

Comment: Form tag is not self-closing.

Comment: I dont think that we should vote more then one downvote - this user will hear the message. Instead, try to help him/her and make him/her good SO citizen.

Comment: I have edited the question a little. It was badly formulated before...

Answer (score 0):

First, change you form tag to </form>.

Why were you expecting that ? HTML tags needs to be properly closed  so the browser can render elements. Yes, browsers are not so strict when it comes to unclosed HTML tags, but best practices shows that all tags inside body should be closed.